# Can you manually add tables and references to SPs/Views/Functions in EF Core Code First to an existing DB?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In EF 6 my work flow was to make all DB changes directly in SQL Server and then manually update/add EF classes to match what's the in the database. What I want to avoid is driving the DB design from code or scaffolding from the DB into EF.

I just want to manually manage everything once the DBContext has been generated.

Is this still possible in EF Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to manually manage everything once the DBContext has been generated. Is this still possible in EF Core?

Absolutely.  Same as in EF 6 Code First, just create the classes and map them to your database objects.